# How can I copy a repeating pattern into a memory buffer?

Tags: c, memcpy

I want write a repeating pattern of bytes into a block of memory. My idea is to write the first example of the pattern, and then copy it into the rest of the buffer. For example, if I start with this:

```
ptr: 123400000000
```

Afterward, I want it to look like this:

```
ptr: 123412341234
```

I thought I could use `memcpy` to write to intersecting regions, like this:

```
memcpy(ptr + 4, ptr, 8);
```

The standard does not specify what order the copy will happen in, so if some implementation makes it copy in reverse order, it can give different results:

```
ptr: 123412340000
```

or even combined results.

Is there any workaround that lets me still use `memcpy`, or do I have to implement my own for loop? Note that I cannot use `memmove` because it does exactly what I'm trying to avoid; it make the ptr be `123412340000`, while I want `123412341234`.

I program for Mac/iPhone(clang compiler) but a general answer will be good too.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the pattern between `ptr` and `ptr + 4` to be repeated up to 8 bytes? If so, you won't get what you want from `memmove` nor `memcpy`.

Comment: @zneak, serial `memcpy` will do that, but I don't know if its serial

Comment: @Dani What does "serial" memcpy mean ?

Comment: @Dani, a specific implementation of `memcpy` *might* do this, but such a use case has an undefined behavior. You can roll your own function that does exactly that.

Comment: It's actually not a duplicate. I'm voting to reopen; I didn't understand the question at first.

Comment: @cnicutar, if a byte-per-byte copy happens with his example, the 4 bytes pattern will be repeated on 8 bytes at once, instead of just 4. This is what he wants.

Comment: The trick that you are trying to use (multiplying a pattern using `memcpy`) is a rather well-known one. However, it doesn't work in accordance with C standard. You cannot use `memcpy` like that in standard C. It is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because OP actually wants something very different than what was asked for. See my comment on Ninefingers' answer. Also -1 to the question for being unclear.

Comment: @AndreyT: Moreover, it makes no sense. What determines the interval at which the pattern propagates? Most likely the optimal unit copying size for the specific machine (not necessarily just the ISA) you run the program on.

Comment: Is the question clearer now, @R..? If not, please edit further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no standard function to repeat a pattern of bytes upon a memory range. You can use the `memset_pattern*` function family to get fixed-size patterns; if you need the size to vary, you'll have to roll your own.

```
// fills the 12 first bytes at `ptr` with the 4 first bytes of `ptr`
memset_pattern4(ptr, ptr, 12);
```

Be aware that `memset_pattern4`, `memset_pattern8` and `memset_pattern16` exist only on Mac OS/iOS, so don't use them for cross-platform development.

Otherwise, rolling a (cross-platform) function that does a byte-per-byte copy is pretty easy.

```
void byte_copy(void* into, void* from, size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        into[i] = from[i];
}
```

Comment: Looks like you just reimplemented `memcpy()` there, which *is* standard.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan There is one subtle difference: this function has a well-defined behavior when `into + size` and `from + size` overlap. `Memcpy`, on the other hand, doesn't.

Comment: For instance, an optimized `memcpy` implementation could choose to read and write chunks of 4-8 bytes at once to go faster. In such a case, if the memory zones overlap, this optimized implementation wouldn't necessarily behave the same as mine.

Comment: True, but in that sense this is still `memcpy()`, since the behaviour for `memcpy()` in that case is undefined.

Comment: If you simply mean that I implemented a basic version of `memcpy`'s algorithm, then we both agree (though you could not use this implementation as a drop-in replacement for `memcpy`, because it's supposed to return a copy of the original memory). Other than that, my implementation differs from the standard `memcpy` in that its behavior is defined when the memory regions overlap, and we cannot use the standard `memcpy` precisely because it does not have this guarantee.

Comment: Indeed, I think we agree here. :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is what [kernel.org](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) says:

> The memcpy() function copies n bytes
>   from memory area src to memory area
>   dest. **The memory areas must not
>   overlap**.  Use memmove(3) if the
>   memory areas do overlap.

An here is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dswaw1wk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says:

> **If the source and destination overlap,
>   the behavior of memcpy is undefined**.
>   Use memmove to handle overlapping
>   regions.

Comment: memmove does exactly what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @Dani Can't you do it in a loop ? I mean keep an offset and increment it with each `memmove`.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ answer for all platforms is std::fill_n(destination, elementRepeats, elementValue).

For what you've asked for:

```
short val = 0x1234;
std::fill_n(ptr, 3, val);
```

This will work for val of any type; chars, shorts, ints, int64_t, etc.

Comment: `std::fill_n()` takes a reference for its third parameter, not a pointer, so it seems to me this answer is wrong, no?  This will fill the memory pointed to by `ptr` with three consecutive copies of the pointer to `val`, not the value of `val`.  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @bhaller Thanks for pointing out the mistake in my example. I've fixed it up but, regardless, fill_n is still the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by copying once, and then `memcpy` everything to copied to the following bytes and repeat that, it's better understood in code:

```
void block_memset(void *destination, const void *source, size_t source_size, size_t repeats) {
    memcpy(destination,source,source_size);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < repeats; i += i)
        memcpy(destination + i,destination,source_size * (min(i,repeats - i)));
}
```

I benchmarked; it's as fast as regular `memset` for large number of `repeats`, and the `source_size` is quite dynamic without much performance penalty too.

Comment: This code is strange, I'm not how pointer arithmetic with `void*` behaves

Answer (score 0):

**Old answer**

You want [`memmove()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memmove.html). Full description:

> The memmove() function shall copy n bytes from the object pointed to by s2 into the object pointed to by s1. Copying takes place as if the n bytes from the object pointed to by s2 are first copied into a temporary array of n bytes that does not overlap the objects pointed to by s1 and s2, and then the n bytes from the temporary array are copied into the object pointed to by s1.

From the [`memcpy()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/memcpy.html) page:

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behaviour is undefined.

<strike>You have to use `memmove()` anyway. This is because  the result of using `memcpy()` is not reliable in any way.</strike>

**Relevant bits to the actual question**

You're asking for `memcpy(ptr + 4, ptr, 8);` which says copy 8 bytes from `ptr` and put them at `ptr+4`. `ptr` is 123400000000, the first 8 bytes are 1234000, so it is doing this:

```
Original : 123400000000
Writes   :     12340000
Result   : 123412340000
```

You'd need to call:

```
memcpy(ptr+4, ptr, 4);
memcpy(ptr+8, ptr, 4);
```

To achieve what you're after. Or implement an equivalent. This ought to do it, but it is untested, and is equivalent to memcpy; you'll need to either add the extra temporary buffer or use two non-overlapping areas of memory.

```
void memexpand(void* result, const void* start, 
               const uint64_t cycle, const uint64_t limit)
{
    uint64_t count = 0;
    uint8_t* source = start;
    uint8_t* dest   = result;

    while ( count < limit )
    {
        *dest = *source;
        dest++;
        count++;

        if ( count % cycle == 0 )
        {
            source = start;
        }
        else
        {
            source++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't use memmove, it does not product the result I want

Comment: @Dani I see what I think you're getting at. You *do* want `memmove`, but you need to use it slightly differently. See edit.

Comment: With OP's changed requirements, `memmove` is not needed. OP merely wants to repeatedly write the same 32-bit (?) pattern across the whole buffer. For this, either a repeated 32-bit `memcpy` (note that regions do not overlap now) for each 32 bits, or `wmemset` (if `sizeof(wchar_t)==4`) will do the job just fine.

Comment: @R.. I've updated my answer, you're right. I've gone with the memcpy repeated, since that's what I had with memmove.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just allocate an 8 byte buffer, move it there, then move it back to where you want it?  (As @cnicutar says, you shouldn't have overlapping address spaces for memcpy.)

Comment: it what memmove does, and I need a different result.